# retrieving the content of parse database in the Recyclerview.Adapter

Tags: android, parse-platform

can anyone direct me on the process of retrieving the content of the parseObject in the database using the Recyclerview.Adapter?
what makes me confused is that extending Recyclerview.Adapter brings few methods to implement, which of the methods should i use to retrieve the data? and in which method should i use the data retrieved?
please anyone can guide me through this

Comment: [tutorial](http://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview/)

Comment: thanks i will read it :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll actually implement this the other way around: you'll use some type of mechanism to get the data from the database (`Loader`, `IntentService`, or some other mechanism).  Once you have the data you'll give it to your `Adapter` and notify the `RecyclerView` or `ListView` of the data set changing.  At that point the `Adapter` will be called on to create/update the `View`s for each item based on the content you have provided.

Comment: its quite complex explaining for me since am still new to all this

Comment: Here's an article I wrote about the basic use of the `Loader` framework which may help.  It uses a `ListView` rather than `RecyclerView`, but the principle is the same with regards to using the Adapter.  It's a very simple example of `Loader` and `Adapter`, but may give you the basic idea. http://po.st/xHoVM

Comment: 404 - Not Found .. the page didn't open